# Setting a url for a page

Tags: urls

Is there a way to set a url for a page, as per the following example:

I want to change this url: http://richardclunan.com/?page_id=2

To: http://richardclunan.com/copy-critiques

Is this possible?

(I clicked Permalink Settings and specified 'copy-critiques' as Category Base, but this didn't do the trick...)

Thanks, Richard

Comment: Any permalink setting(exception to default) uses that exact structure for pages, there's nothing special you need set, simply choose any permalink option aside from default(in Admin > Settings > Permalinks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the [permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) to `%postname%`, however this would change the permalinks for the whole site;

and you can set the individual page permalink, which is normally derived from the page title, when you edit the page.

btw: pages don't have a category base.